# c++ copy constructor related query

Tags: c++, algorithm, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

```
#include<iostream>
class A{
    public :
        int a;
};
int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.a = 5;
    A b(obj);

    b.a = 6;
    std::cout<<obj.a;
    return 0;

}
```

why is the answer returned as 5 , by default copy constructor in C++ returns a shallow copy. Isn't the shallow copy means reference ??
or m i missing something ?

Comment: If it didn't make a copy, why would it be called a copy constructor? Note that shallow vs. deep is a bit irrelevant, as there's nothing to deep copy in your example.

Comment: Why do you think `obj.a` will change unless you explicitly change state of `obj`?

Comment: i think compiler will return reference of obj to a  , that is y i thought this

Comment: @Peter: No the copy constructor as the name suggests returns a copy of the object it receives as an argument.

Comment: okay so but in java when we pass objects in functions , the copy constructor is called then also right , then y is it by reference then , does java's copy constructor by default returns reference , is there no significance of word copy there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> shallow copy means reference ?? or m i missing something ?

You are missing something. **Shallow copy means copy**. It copies all the members of the object from one to another. It is NOT a reference. The copy created is completely independent of the original

See [this excellent tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/) for the difference between shallow and deep copy.

Comment: then what is deep copy if anyways shallow copy is making a copy

Comment: @Peter, If you have a pointer, it will copy the pointer, not what it points to. Copying what it points to has to be done explicitly. That's a deep copy.

Comment: okay so but in java when we pass objects in functions , the copy constructor is called then also right , then y is it by reference then , does java's copy constructor by default returns reference , is there no significance of word copy there

Comment: @Peter In java they are passed by value, not by copy constructor. AFAIK even in java a copy constructor does create a new copy, but the difference being it has to be explicitly called.

Comment: @Peter Reference the way you think of it is a Java term. Closest is a pointer in C. But that has nothing to do with this question. Java copy constructor returns a reference to a copy of the original, not a reference to the original

Answer (score 2):

`b` is a completely separate object from `obj`. It has its own `a` independent of `obj`'s.

It sounds like what you have in mind is a *reference*:

```
A& b = obj;
```

After this, both `b` and `obj` refer to the same object. Changes made through `b` would be visible through `obj` and vice versa.

Comment: i thought default copy construtor will return reference of the object in b of obj

Comment: @Peter: No it doesn't. The two objects are completely separate.

Answer (score 2):

> shallow copy means reference ?? or m i missing something ?

Yes, you're missing something.

Shallow copy doesn't mean reference. Shallow copy means *copying* the members : if a member is a pointer, then it *copies* the address, not the *content* the pointer is *pointing to*. That means, the pointers in the original object and the so-called copied object point to the *same content* in memory. That is called shallow copy. Deep copy, on the other hand, doesn't copy the address, it creates a new pointer (in the new object), allocates memory for it, and then copies *the content* the original pointer points to.

In your case, shallow copy and deep copy make no difference because there are no pointer member(s) in the class. Every member is copied *(as usual)*, and since no member is a pointer, each copied member is a *different* member in memory. That is, the original object and the copied object are completely different objects in memory. There is absolutely nothing that the two objects share with each other. So when you modify one, it doesn't at all change anything in the other.

Comment: okay so but in java when we pass objects in functions , the copy constructor is called then also right , then y is it by reference then , does java's copy constructor by default returns reference , is there no significance of word copy there

Comment: @Peter: I don't know Java. And C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default copy constructor is a shallow copy. See more [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/)

But, b is completely disjoint from a, so the two things are not related directly.

Answer (score 0):

`A b(obj)` copies `obj` information into the newly created object `b`. Yes it's a shallow copy so `b` does not actually control what's being assigned to it. What you're probably thinking about is a reference:

```
A& b = obj;

b.a = 6;

std::cout << obj.a; // 6
```